# Crash reports show up in App Store Connect but not in Xcode Organizer

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight, crash-reports

We've uploaded our app to TestFlight for beta testing. When the app crashes on a tester's device the crash shows up in App Store Connect as expected, but not in the Xcode Organizer. The crashes  tab in the organizer is showing the correct version and build, but instead of the crashes we only see the following message: "No crash logs reported for this version in the last two weeks."

What has to be done for the crashes to show up in the Xcode Organizer?

Additional information:

- Xcode 12.0
- Symbol files were included when uploading to App Store Connect.
- Developer account has the necessary rights to see crash information.

What we've tried so far:

- Restarting Xcode.
- Removing and re-adding the developer account inside Xcode.
- Updating to Xcode 12.2

Comment: Having the same problem. Would be nice to have these reports!

Comment: We ended up using Visual Studio App Center, but now that I have checked again, the crashes have actually started showing up in the organizer as well.

Comment: Nice yeah I'm thinking I'll have to go with crashlytics. Thanks, looks like crashes from two days ago are showing up for me now but no sign of one from yesterdays updated build.

Comment: same problem with me: Xcode 14.1

Comment: Same problem. Cannot load crash logs in Xcode.

Comment: Same problem. When I tested on app, crash was due to paste in textfield. Cross checked and it is the issue of iOS 16.6. Does crash outside of our code doesn't show up ?